# Calling scalar function through Exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, execute

I have created a scalar function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Dumm()
returns INT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @a INT
      SELECT @a = 1
      RETURN @a
  END
```

Now I am calling the scalar function through `Exec` not through `select`

```
EXEC dbo.Dumm
```

It did not return `1`. It just says

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Whats happening internally. Is there any meaning for it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ret int;
EXEC @ret = dbo.Dumm
```

and then show the result querying your variable @ret as follow:

```
SELECT @ret
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Actualy EXEC statement executing the function & giving output. But we need to capture if we need. @Prdp